# Increasing the response rate to requests for photos/info/clarification

Tags: discussion

In my short time here, it seems quite common that the initial content/articulateness of a Q is insufficient (perhaps expectedly so), and that it is common for requests for clarification or for additional information/photos to go unmet.

What are the thoughts on why such requests go unmet?

If any, what changes have been made to the forum to increase the response rate?  Did they work?

Answer (score 5):

I suspect most of these are drive-by questions before the OP searches elsewhere for the answer, and then they never return to see that we've answered their question. Since asking a question doesn't require any contact information, only a browser cookie that may be easily lost, it's difficult to recover these questions.

If you're able to answer the question with "if A then B" to cover the possible scenarios, then that's the best option since it has the best opportunity to help the OP and future visitors.

If there's no way to answer the question, then leave a comment explaining why and cast a vote to hold/close the question as "unclear what you're asking". I'm much more likely to cast a binding vote to hold/close a question if I see others in the community agree.

Some people will be more likely to resolve a problem with their question once it's placed on hold. And if it was a drive-by question, there wasn't much of a chance to save it and it prevents the question from being bumped by `community` for being unanswered.